# Bundle install tries to use cache file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

When i try to do bundle install, my gem_path and gem_home point to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ which i don't have write access and it fails because of invalid permissions. because of this i've changed both paths to a local directory where i do have write access.

when doing so, i do  a bundle install, i get :

```
bruno@test6:~$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at   /afs/varda.io/user/b/br/bruno/test6/cache/rake-10.1.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

well, if i do a gem install, it works just fine.

but bundle would just not work; even if a try to delete the cache folder that it complains about.

i did try "bundle install --no-cache" and it fails in the same way. (bundle install --deployment works fine too) how do i get bundle install to work ?

i've spent quite a bit of time, if anyone would have any guidance , i would really appreciate it!

Comment: what if you try `GEM_HOME=/path/you/can/write/to bundle install` ?

Comment: thanks Anko. I've already donde that ; the outcome is the same.

Comment: Are you on a unix system? I find the strace tool useful.  `strace bundle install` will show you all the system calls which will tell you which files are trying to be opened and where it's failing.

Comment: are you an admin? why don't you give yourself write access to `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

okay, first of all, you could solve all this issues easily by using rvm (user installation), see http://rvm.io, if that is not an option, you could try using project-specific gem paths. 
for example i have the following bundler config file (`~/.bundle/config`)

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: .bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
```

which causes bundler to install all gems in a `.bundle` sub directory (inside your project folder, where you run `bundle install`). now, if you remember to use `bundle exec` for your bins (e.g. cap(istrano)), you're fine.

if you somehow f*cked up your bundler / cache, try deleting the `.bundle` folder (in your project folder)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marian, actually rvm was causing a conflict. i was using rvm, but not to install individual gems, i re-imaged my ubuntu box,and installed rails without rvm, the problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks Marian, this worked for me and helped me understand what it was doing.  Instead of installing the gems in a `.bundle` sub directory, I put them in a tmp folder.                                                                                                    `---
BUNDLE_PATH: "/tmp/project-bundle"
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'  `

Answer (score 19):

Fixed it by deleting cache file and re-running bundle install.

rm -rf <location_of_cache>. In your case:

```
rm -rf /afs/varda.io/user/b/br/bruno/test6/cache
```

Comment: `mv <location_of_cache>/<gemname>.gem ~/.Trash/` works well, and provides a fallback option in Trash in case you mess something up.

Answer (score 1):

`rvm reinstall all` worked for me.

Before you do that, I would try

```
gem update --system
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

---

please note that `rvm reinstall all` takes a lot of time to complete...

Answer (score 1):

If it's feasible, I recommend installing your own copy of `rvm` in `~/.rvm` so you aren't tied to the system one. Trying to have a hybrid system+user approach will likely lead to more headaches later on.

Or, if you're open to alternate solutions, `rbenv` is a leaner & cleaner ruby manager.

Comment: what kind of headaches might it lead to?

Comment: Like constantly needing to set `GEM_HOME` (and possibly rearranging the ordering in `GEM_PATH`), trying to understand the `gem` flags like `--user-install`, having to add yet another directory to your `$PATH` if you want to easily run executables. The bottom line is that rvm already does crazy things with your environment variables, and it might even stop working if you upgrade rvm.

Comment: And furthermore, if you try to run `GEM_HOME`-sensitive commands via Capistrano, cron jobs, daemons, or even ruby's `system` method, you're going to start wanting to shoot yourself. You'll go mad trying to remember when and how to pass environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tell to `bundler` which folder it must use, something like `bundle install --path <myfolder>` or `bundle install --path gems`.

Note that I didn't test this yet, but it seems promising, please post the result for us.